# Why pass a generator into iter to use its generator function?

Tags: python, python-2.7, generator, sequence

If we consider the following generator and the generator function:

```
def integers():
    """Infinite sequence of integers."""
    i = 1
    while True:
        yield i
        i = i + 1

def take(n, seq):
    """Returns first n values from the given sequence."""
    seq = iter(seq)
    result = []
    try:
        for i in range(n):
            result.append(seq.next())
    except StopIteration:
        pass
    return result

print take(5, integers()) # prints [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Why does the built-in iter function have to be called onto the generator in the generator function? The code still runs and prints the correct value without it.

Comment: Try to remove that line and pass a list to take. `take([1, 2, 3], 2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`take` does not know whether it receives a iterator (such as a generator) or a container (such as a list/tuple/set). In the latter case, containers do not have a `.next` method associated with them, so your code will fail. Your code is playing it safe rather than taking a chance, which I'd consider good programming practice.

---

An example (in python3):

```
def foo():
     yield from [1, 2, 3]

x = iter([1, 2, 3])
y = iter(foo())

print( next(x), next(y) ) # this would be `x.next()` in python2
(1, 1)
```

In the latter case, the `iter` is redundant, but it the code works in both cases. However, consider:

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
print(next(x))
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-351-cf05c93171ef> in <module>()
----> 1 print(next(x))

TypeError: 'list' object is not an iterator
```

It should be clear why the `iter` call is needed.

Comment: Iterators *are* iterables. This is required by the [iterator spec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator.__iter__).

Comment: @user2357112 I'm struggling to find the right wording... what is appropriate here?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ You could refer to them as containers.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye Thanks!

Comment: I usually go for wording like "some other iterable" or "non-iterator iterable" to accomodate particularly weird iterables, but "container" covers most non-iterator iterables and avoids implying that iterators aren't iterables.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass a `list` or `tuple` to your `take` function, they won't have a `next` method.

```
>>> [1, 2, 3].next() # AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'next'
```

Using `iter` on a `list` will give you a `listiterator`, which does have a `next` method.

```
>>> my_gen = iter([1, 2, 3])
>>> print(my_gen)
<listiterator object at 0x108390a10>
>>> my_gen.next()
1
>>> next(my_gen)
2
```

Comment: `listiterator` is an iterator, but not a generator